Locking system won't turn off screen after set 5 minutes
I am getting this with a nVidia GTX 1050 and 550 drivers in 24.04.1.
Instead of turning the screen off I get a black screen and my mouse cursor shown.
I've found a similar question for ubuntu 15.xx but there has not been posted an answer.

Does the black screen have any text on it, such as the date and time?
